# Duplicate ID error with Partial State Saving and MyFaces CODI

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, myfaces, codi

I am developing a JSF web application using PrimeFaces3.3, MyFaces+CODI, OpenWebBeans and Tomcat7.

I am getting duplicate Id error after display of a specif page (all subsequent page actions). Analyzing viewroot with debug, I couldn't really find any duplicate id but I found that 'WindowContextIdHolderComponent' has the id (j_id6) which is thrown as duplicate.

I started having this issue ever since I have made the PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING to 'true'.

I have a main view that has tabs and with in each tab there are menus and each menu actions loads the page with in the tab using

Below is the code and structure of my application.

Main page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="/templates/simple3section.xhtml">

<ui:define name="headerarea">
    Banner Comes Here
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="contents">
<p:tabView dynamic="false" cache="false" id="mainTab">
    <p:tab title="Home">
        <ui:include src="employeehome.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Academics">
        <ui:include src="academicmain.xhtml" /> 
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Transport">
        <ui:include src="transportmain.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Administration">
        <ui:include src="adminmain.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Finance" disabled="true">
        <ui:include src="financemain.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Shop" >
        <ui:include src="shopmain.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>        
</p:tabView>
</ui:define>    
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Adminmain.xhtml page (the tab page)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>
<div>
    <h:form>
        <p:menubar style="margin-bottom:5px;">
            <p:menuitem value="Employees" icon="ui-icon-star" ajax="true"
                actionListener="#{homeNavigationBean.setAdminPage('employeeinfo')}"
                update=":mainTab:adminContent">
            </p:menuitem>
            <p:menuitem value="Employee Authorization" icon="ui-icon-star" ajax="true"
                actionListener="#{homeNavigationBean.setAdminPage('authorization')}"
                update=":mainTab:adminContent">
            </p:menuitem>
            <p:menuitem value="Notices" icon="ui-icon-star" ajax="true"
                action="#{homeNavigationBean.setAdminPage('notices')}"
                actionListener="#{noticesBean.loadNotices(false)}"
                update=":mainTab:adminContent">
            </p:menuitem>
            <p:menuitem id="updgallery" value="Gallery" icon="ui-icon-star" ajax="true"  
                actionListener="#{homeNavigationBean.setAdminPage('adminGallery')}" 
                update=":mainTab:adminContent">
            </p:menuitem>
            <p:menuitem value="Location" icon="ui-icon-star" ajax="true"
                action="#{homeNavigationBean.setAdminPage('location')}"
                actionListener="#{locationBean.loadLocation}"
                update=":mainTab:adminContent">
            </p:menuitem>
            <p:menuitem value="Department" icon="ui-icon-star" ajax="true"
                action="#{homeNavigationBean.setAdminPage('department')}"
                actionListener="#{departmentBean.loadDepartment}"
                update=":mainTab:adminContent">
            </p:menuitem>
        </p:menubar>
    </h:form>
</div>
<div>
    <p:outputPanel id="adminContent" layout="block" style="border-style: none; padding: 0;">
            <ui:include src="admin/#{homeNavigationBean.adminPage}.xhtml" />
    </p:outputPanel>
    </div>
   </h:body>
   </html>
```

and below is the adminGallery page that causes the Duplicate Id error (all other pages don't have this problem)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>
<p:panelGrid style="width:98%;">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:row>
            <p:column colspan="2">
        <h:outputText value="Image Gallary"></h:outputText>  
    </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </f:facet>
    <p:row>
        <p:column style="width:200px;vertical-align:top">
            <h:form id="nodeForm">
                <p:tree id="nodeTree" value="#{galleryBean.imageTree}" var="node"
                    selectionMode="single" selection="#{galleryBean.selectedNode}" 
                    style="width:160px;border-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;">
                    <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{galleryBean.loadImages}"
                        update=":mainTab:imageForm:galaPanel" />
                    <p:treeNode id="treeNode">
                        <h:outputText value="#{node}"></h:outputText>
                    </p:treeNode>
                </p:tree>
            </h:form>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:form id="imageForm">
                <p:outputPanel id="galaPanel">
                    <p:galleria var="image" id="imgGala"
                        value="#{galleryBean.imageList}" panelWidth="470"
                        style="padding:0;margin:0;">
                        <p:graphicImage value="#{imageHelper.getFilePhotoStream()}"
                            width="450">
                            <f:param name="imageName" value="#{image}" />
                        </p:graphicImage>
                    </p:galleria>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </h:form>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>

    <p:row>
        <p:column>
            <h:form id="nodeAddForm">
                <p:messages id="treemsgs" style="padding:0;margin:0;" />
                <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%">
                    <h:outputText value="Name:*" />
                    <p:inputText id="nodename" value="#{galleryBean.name}"
                        label="Node Name" />

                    <h:outputText value="External Visible:" />
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="extcheck"
                        value="#{galleryBean.externalvisible}" />
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton type="Submit" value="Add New Node"
                            actionListener="#{galleryBean.addImageNode}" ajax="true"
                            process="nodename extcheck" update=":mainTab:nodeForm:nodeTree treemsgs" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:form id="imageAddForm">
                <p:messages id="imgmsgs" />
                <p:fileUpload mode="advanced"
                    fileUploadListener="#{galleryBean.addPhotoFile}"
                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g)$/" sizeLimit="1000000"
                    invalidSizeMessage="Please limit photo size to 1000Kb"
                    update=":mainTab:imageForm:galaPanel imgmsgs" />
            </h:form>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
<p:spacer height="20"/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

This page is displayed correctly,but all request post the display of this page fail with Duplicate Id error.

My Bean is CODI WindowScoped.

Based on various suggested answers around Duplicate Id, I see only ui:include as the potential source of the problem. But since I don't have any problem with other pages with in the tab or across the tabs, I suspect that that is not the issue.

Please suggest what could be the issue here and potential fix.

Comment: Which version of MyFaces Core are you using?

Comment: It looks like it isn't a CODI bug, I just found https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3660 .